# Angular Bootstrap: Navigation disappears on iPad Safari Scroll

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, mobile-safari

Angular 8, Bootstrap 4.6

There is a fixed navigation bar at the top of the screen.  On iPad Safari ***only***: when the user scrolls down, the navigation bar disappears.  When the user scrolls up there is white space where the navigation bar should be.  It does not reappear unless the user refreshes the page.  This only occurs when in portrait mode.

It works as expected in every other environment.

Most of the other questions I found on this involve items disappearing during scroll and then reappearing, but this is definitely ***not*** reappearing.

The css used to have position:fixed.  I changed it to position:absolute but that had no effect.

.html:

```
<nav #navbar *ngIf="userName" myHideGlobalNav
      class="navbar navbar-default{} navbar-expand-md ">
     <div class="container-fluid ">
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <div class="navbar-brand"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
             <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                 <customer-selector></customer-selector>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link"
                        routerLink="/orders"
                        routerLinkActive="active"
                     >Orders
                     </a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav {{tooSmall ? '' : 'ml-sm-auto'}}">
                 <div>
                     <li class="nav-item dropdown profile" dropdown>
                         <a dropdownToggle class="nav-link no-hover dropdown-link dropdown-toggle">
                             <div class="profile-icon">{{userAvatar}}</div>
                             <span class="name">{{userName}}</span>
                         </a>
                         <ul *dropdownMenu role="menu" class="profile-dropdown dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                             <li role="menuitem">
                                 <a class="dropdown-item"
                                    routerLink="/profile"
                                 >My Profile</a></li>
                             </li>
                             <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
                             <li role="menuitem">
                                 <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/login',{'logout':true}]">Log Out</a>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                 </div>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

.scss:

```
 .nav-up {
     top: -$nav-height !important;
 }
 
 .navbar {
     height: $nav-height;
     background-color: $ocean-blue;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 15px;
     margin: 0px;
     border-radius: 0px;
     border: none;
     min-width: 970px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 12;
     .navbar-brand {
         background: transparent url(../../../assets/img/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
         background-size: contain;
         height: 50px;
         width: 164px;
         margin-left: -5px;
         margin-right: 5px;
         margin-top: 3px;
     }
 
     li > a {
         opacity: 0.72;
         font-size: 1.067rem;
         text-align: center;
         color: #ffffff;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         padding: 21px 12px 10px 12px;
         &:hover {
             background-color: rgba(0, 116, 176, 0.05);
         }
         &.dropdown-link {
             text-transform: none;
         }
         &.dropdown-link.no-hover {
             &:hover {
                 background-color: transparent;
             }
         }
         &.icon {
             opacity: 1;
         }
         &.active {
             opacity: 1;
             background: transparent url(../../../assets/img/global-nav-top-bg-white.png) repeat-x top center;
             position: relative;
             padding-top: 21px;
             &.dropdown.dropdown-hover .dropdown-menu {
                 display: none;
             }
         }
         &.active-small {
             background-color: rgba(0, 116, 176, 0.05);
         }
     }
     div.counter {
         width: 37px;
         height: 28px;
         border-radius: 70px;
         background-color: $mango;
         border: solid 2px #ffffff;
         text-align: center;
         line-height: 22px;
         top: -2px;
         position: relative;
     }
     li.counter {
         opacity: 1;
     }
 
 }
 
 .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav{
     align-items: center;
 }
 
 :host ::ng-deep .nav {
     .open > a {
         background-color: transparent;
     }
 }
 
 .nav {
     .open > a {
         background-color: transparent;
     }
 }
 
 .navbar-nav > div > li > .dropdown-menu {
     padding-top: 0px;
     border-top: 0px;
     color: $black-84;
     font-size: 1rem;
     border-top-right-radius: 4px;
     border-top-left-radius: 4px;
     .divider {
         margin: 0;
     }
     .dropdown-header {
         font-size: 0.867rem;
         color: $black-84;
         background-color: $pale-grey;
         border-bottom: solid 1px $cool-grey;
         border-left: solid 1px $cool-grey;
         border-right: solid 1px $cool-grey;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
         border-top-right-radius: 4px;
         border-top-left-radius: 4px;
     }
     input[type='search'] {
         width: 224px;
         height: 40px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         background-color: #ffffff;
         border: solid 1px $ocean-blue-40;
         margin-left: 16px;
     }
     li:not(.divider):not(.dropdown-header) {
         min-height: 40px;
     }
     a {
         font-size: 15px;
         line-height: 1.6;
         color: $black-84;
         text-transform: none;
         text-align: left;
         white-space: nowrap;
         padding: 7px 16px 9px 16px;
     }
 }
```

hide-nav.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowRef } from '../../core/window.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myHideNav]'
})

export class HideNavDirective {

    didScroll: boolean;
    lastScrollTop: number = 0;
    delta: number = 5;

    navShown: boolean = true;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private winRef: WindowRef) {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (this.didScroll) {
                this.hasScrolled();
                this.didScroll = false;
            }
        }, 250);
    }

    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) hideNav(event) {
        this.didScroll = true;
    }

    private hasScrolled() {
        let st = this.winRef.nativeWindow.pageYOffset;

        if (Math.abs(this.lastScrollTop - st) <= this.delta) {
            return;
        }

        if (st > this.lastScrollTop && st > 80) {
            this.navShown = false;
            this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('nav-up');
        } else {
            if (st + this.winRef.nativeWindow.screen.height >= document.documentElement.clientHeight || st === 0) {
                this.navShown = true;
                this.el.nativeElement.classList.remove('nav-up');
            }
        }
        this.lastScrollTop = st;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for curly brackets in navbar-default{}? Could it be the case that Safari cannot digest it?

Comment: Not sure why the curly brackets are there (I didn't write it) but removing them has no effect, unfortunately.